# New Google Publisher

Tags: java, android, google-play

I develop an android app. one for paid and other is free app. 
Now I want to upload these app to the play store.

But there are some questions in my mind:

1.What is Alpha and Beta testing?

2.If these both testings are necessary for all apps.(free and paid both)?

3.Can I upload my app without these 2 tests?

4.If these test not pass then what can am I do?

5.Google charge extra fee for these tests.?

I visit Google publisher Help center. But still I'm really confuse please help me...

Comment: Tests are optional but they provide to you valuable parameters about current state of your application. If you decide to publish apk without tests, you will never be sure is your app works as you developed it for various devices. In that case there can be a lot of bugs related to many aspects and you will be faced with bad reputation on this app and number of downloads of this app will be small.

Comment: o....this is good one. its very important. Now i fully understand about these tests. Thanks to Bosko Mijin and all experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1> What is Alpha and Beta testing?**

**Alpha Testing**

```
1. It is always performed by the developers at the software development
site.
2. Sometimes it is also performed by Independent Testing Team.
3. Alpha Testing is not open to the market and public
4. It is conducted for the software application and project.
5. It is always performed in Virtual Environment.
6. It is always performed within the organization.
7. It is the form of Acceptance Testing.
8. Alpha Testing is definitely performed and carried out at the developing organizations location with the involvement of
developers.
9. It comes under the category of both White Box Testing and Black Box Testing.
10. Alpha Testing is always performed at the time of Acceptance Testing when developers test the product and project to check
whether it meets the user requirements or not.
11. It is always performed at the developer’s premises in the absence of the users.
12. Alpha Testing is not known by any other different name.
13. It is considered as the User Acceptance Testing (UAT) which is done at developer’s area.
```

**Beta Testing (Field Testing)**

```
1.It is always performed by the customers at their own site.
2. It is not performed by Independent Testing Team.
3. Beta Testing is always open to the market and public.
4. It is usually conducted for software product.
5. It is performed in Real Time Environment.
6. It is always performed outside the organization.
7. It is also the form of Acceptance Testing.
8. Beta Testing (field testing) is performed and carried out by users or you can say people at their own locations and site using customer data.
9. It is only a kind of Black Box Testing.
10. Beta Testing is always performed at the time when software product and project are marketed.
11. It is always performed at the user’s premises in the absence of the development team. 12 Beta Testing is also known by the name Field Testing means it is also known as field testing.
13. It is also considered as the User Acceptance Testing (UAT) which is done at customers or users area.
```

**2.If these both testings are necessary for all apps.(free and paid both)?**

No. But required to test the application before uploading on market. As the erroneous application leads to so many negative feedbacks.

**3.Can I upload my app without these 2 tests?**

Yes, You can upload it.

**4.If these test not pass then what can am I do?**

Resolve the issues of your application and regenerate the apk and again upload it in market.

**5.Google charge extra fee for these tests.?**

No charges are required.

Answer (score 0):

**1.What is Alpha and Beta testing?**

In Google Play you can Publish APK with new features for a limited set of users (that you choose) for testing purposes. If you have good feedbacks you can promote the APK to "production" (for all users), otherwise you can make corrections.

**2.If these both testings are necessary for all apps.(free and paid both)?**

Testing are optional for both free and paid apps.

**3.Can I upload my app without these 2 tests?**

Yes, you can, but keep in mind that tests are useful. App with bugs may produce negative feedbacks. With negative feedbacks you will loose downloads.

**4.If these test not pass then what can am I do?**

You can correct the bugs and upload another APK for further testing.

**5.Google charge extra fee for these tests.?**

Publishing tests is free.

Comment: So, if we test our app very very hardly. then no Alpha and/or beta test require. ok?

Comment: @user3153149 Yes right.